# How to reset/remove authentication supplied for remote file access in Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking

When you try to access a remote location from Windows Explorer e.g. `\\test-server\folder` you are normally presented a standard login dialog so you can chose who to access the location as.

Windows remembers your authentication so in future it just works. But what if you want to change the authenticated user, or remove this for some reason - maybe you did it on someone else's PC and you don't want them to have access?

Where can I go to find/change/clear cached credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't click "Remember password": Reboot, or log out from Windows. (Also, next time use `net use` to establish the connection – it doesn't cache passwords at all, so it's enough to disconnect via `net use /d`, whereas Windows Explorer caches passwords until logout.

If you *did* click "Remember password": Open the *Credential Manager* control panel, go to the "Windows Credentials" section and delete things from there. (You can also do this using `cmdkey`.) *Then* reboot the system, or log out from Windows.